# A horror movie similar to poltergeist and the conjuring

Tags: story-identification, movie

A long time ago (80's or 90's) I saw a good horror movie and I would like to watch it again, but I have no idea what the title was or the names of any of the actors.

Here's what I can remember:
- it is a ghost movie similar to "Poltergeist" or the more recent "The Conjuring", and like those movies, a family is haunted by a supernatural presence in their house.

- most of the times the entity manifests itself the people present in the room can also sense a "foul smell", like rotten fish, besides the usual objects moving / falling down
- a medium called to help them tells them there are four presences in the house, three ghosts and a demon who is controlling the ghosts and making them "do things"
- a cool simple scene shows the wife telling her husband that she can hear "voices in her pillow", he then leans in and then throws the pillow away in terror
- when the family returns from a vacation the neighbours tell them there were screams and loud noises coming from their house
- in the end the family moves to another house but shadows are shown in the new house, telling the viewer that the presences have moved with them

Can anyone identify this? It's probably a TV movie. I don't think it had any known movie stars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[The Haunted](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102007/)*

> The Smurl family move into their new home on Chase Street only to find
>   that it is plagued with three spirits and a demon. The demon wants to
>   destroy their family and they are constantly desperate until they find
>   the Warren family to get rid of them.

Based on a true story even! Good luck finding a copy of it anywhere other than YouTube though.

Comment: Interesting side note:  The "true" story is an admitted hoax.  The family admitted that the Warrens convinced them to play along because their story would make them rich.  The same is true of all of the movies based on Warren-family stories as well.

Comment: Yep, thanks, I think that's it! And the family dad is one of the "walking dead" stars. :)